# Return an array of all checkboxes checked upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I've got a table with a checkbox in each row, like this:

```
<table id='users'>
    <thead>
    ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='users' id='someUserId'></td>
            <td> some variable pid </td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='users' id='someOtherId'></td>
            <td> some other variable pid </td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i want to put the text of the columns next to the checkboxes, the pids, into an array, then pass the array to a function. The function should take each record in the array and process them.

My best try so far:

```
function myFunction(arr[]){...}

function getIds(obj){
var $table = $("#users");
alert($table.attr("id"));
var $cboxes = $table.find("input:checkbox").toArray();
alert($cboxes);

var checkedArray = [];
var pid;
for(i = 0;i < $cboxes.length; i++){
    if($cboxes[i].checked){
        pid = $cboxes.parent().siblings().eq(0).text();
        checkedArray.push(pid);
        alert(pid);
    }
}
alert(checkedArray);
return checkedArray;
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    var ids = getIds();

    for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
        myFunction(ids[i]);
        alert("Function executed for "+ids[i]+".");
    }
});
```

Comment: You could do $( "input:checked" ) and you wouldn't have to verify each is one is checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slim this down heavily with the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo-selector, and [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```js
function process (id) {
  alert(id);
}
function find () {
  return $('#users').find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).parent().next().text();
  }).toArray();
}

function handle () {
  find().forEach(process);
}

$('#btn').on('click', handle); // Pseudo-event
```

```html
<table id='users'>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='users' id='someUserId'></td>
      <td> some variable pid </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='users' id='someOtherId'></td>
      <td> some other variable pid </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btn">Check!</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to loop twice, you should compress the logic into a single function chain. This cuts down on loops, but still builds the array for later use.

```js
var myNamespace = {};

function process (id) {
  alert('Single ID: '+ id);
  return id;
}
function find () {
  return $('#users').find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return process($(this).parent().next().text());
  }).toArray();
}

function handle () {
  myNamespace.ids = find();
  alert('All IDs: ' + myNamespace.ids)
}

$('#btn').on('click', handle); // Pseudo-event
```

```html
<table id='users'>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='users' id='someUserId'></td>
      <td> some variable pid </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='users' id='someOtherId'></td>
      <td> some other variable pid </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btn">Check!</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) ! Btw, how did you make those "run code snippet" buttons?

Comment: Inside the editor, on the little toolbar, there's a [code-snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) button. Looks like a page with `<>` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd7taska/)

```
 function getIds() {
     var chk = $("#users").find("input:checkbox");
     var pId = [];

     chk.each(function(){
         pId.push($(this).parent().next().html());
     });

     return pId;
 }

 $(function(){
     getIds().forEach(function(i){
         console.log(i);
     });
 });
```

Find all checkboxes inside the users table, create array, push all pId's into the array then return it from the function. Then just loop through them all.